# Is there a name for this in linear algebra, and if so what is it?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I have read about Hadamard products between two matrices. I am on a quest to find something very similar for computing average cross-entropy gradient given:

$$
\nabla E_j = (x_{1j}(y_j - \hat{y_j}), \dots, x_{nj}(y_j - \hat{y_j}))
$$

and

$$X=
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots & x_{2n} \\
     \\
    x_{m1}       & x_{m2} & x_{m3} & \dots & x_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to compose an equation such that $X$ times something else gives me:

\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}(y_1 - \hat{y_1}) & \dots & x_{1n}(y_1 - \hat{y_1}) \\
     x_{21}(y_2 - \hat{y_2}) & \dots & x_{2n}(y_2 - \hat{y_2}) \\
     \\
    x_{31}(y_3 - \hat{y_3}) & \dots & x_{3n}(y_3 - \hat{y_3})
\end{bmatrix}

So basically, I want to compose a matrix whose rows are essentially the rows of X each multiplied by the scalar $y_j - \hat{y}_j$

I have found a way to do this with Numpy:

```
(X.T * (y - y_hat)).T
```

Which in mathy notation is essentially this:

$$
(X^T * (y - \hat{y}))^T
$$

I am wondering if this `*` operation in Numpy has a name. It is not (I don't think) an inner product of any kind. Does it have a basis in standard linear algebra?

Answer (score 0):

You could think of it as just the dot product between the vector X where all your columns are organized into a vector and the vector Y which is your $y - \hat{y}$ vector repeated m times, and clearly this space of vectors is a metric space. So just take your matrices and put them as vectors (this clearly is an isomorphism) and your $y - \hat{y}$ repeated m times (which will be an element of this space) and will end up working with the normal old dot product over the field you're working on.

Comment: So does the `*` operation I have outlined here have a name?

Comment: I mean, you could view it as the normal inner product between vectors. So all the properties you know about $\mathbb{R}^n $ and $\mathbb{C}^n $ will be valid for this * operation.